# Est-ce qu'on « vend la mèche » d'un film : usage ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, locutions

L'expression « [vendre la mèche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A8che) » [ ]  signifie:<sup>1</sup>

> *Vendre la mèche (au fig. et fam.)*. Dénoncer un complot, dévoiler une combinaison. *J'ai besoin de cent francs... si l'oncle ne me donne pas
>   cent francs, je vends la mèche* (Zola,*Pot-Bouille*, 1882, p.135).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi - « mèche » A.2.b. ]

On peut facilement imaginer le contexte usuel de l'échange avec une personne qui a vu un film alors qu'on ne l'a pas vu. La personne s'apprête par exemple à révéler des détails qu'on veut éviter de savoir pour ne pas gâcher notre expérience lors du visionnement de l’œuvre. C'est le cas du fameux  « [spoiler](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spoiler&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) » en langue anglaise.

Quand cette situation se présente et que j'interviens, puis-je dire:

> Ne vends pas la mèche! 
> Ne vends pas la mèche du film!

Est-ce que cette expression est convenablement utilisée dans les deux cas ici, et existe-t-il des expressions ou manières de s'exprimer équivalentes et plus usuelles (pour le contexte en question - cinéma/télé) ?

---

<sub>1. Le sens premier de la *mèche* en soi c'est celui du *cordon que l'on fait brûler*; l'étymologie participe de l'idée de *moisissure* et trucs *muqueux* - je paraphrase le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous la dir. d'A. Rey, aux ed. *Le Robert*. « *Éventer la mèche* » ça provient littéralement de l'opération de déminage («découvrir, au moyen d'une contremine, l'endroit où une mine a été pratiquée et enlever la mèche qui devait la faire jouer» 1580 - *TLFi*). En 1690 passe dans l'usage «découvrir, déceler un projet un complot» (*TLFi*); *découvrir la mèche* précède. Puis « [vendre la mèche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vendre%20la%20m%C3%A8che&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvendre%20la%20m%C3%A8che%3B%2Cc0) » serait début 19e - 1859 *TLFi*; 1830 Rey; je vois [Ducange](https://books.google.com/books?id=xPRKAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22vendre%20la%20m%C3%A8che%22&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=%22vendre%20la%20m%C3%A8che%22&f=false) 1819. D'autre part, il faut noter que la première attestation en français du verbe [*vendre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vendre) est celle de « trahir »; autrement ça origine du latin avec *vendere*, et « vanter » de *venum dare* ... *venditare*. (Rey).</sub>

Comment: En langage familier et moderne, l'anglicisme convient parfaitement: `Ne me spoil pas !`

Comment: @iKiWiXz « Ne me » ou « ne le » ou « ne me le » ? ;-)

Comment: « Ne me » ou « Ne me le » voire peut-être même « Ne ».

Comment: @iKiWiXz Intéressant, merci. Le point plus faible selon moi c'est lorsqu'on compare _spoiler_ et _to spoil_ en anglais; on voit que le premier a le sens d'une information qui dévoile, alors que le verbe n'a pas formellement ce sens. Ainsi _don't give away/out spoilers_ et _don't spoil_ sont différents. Tant qu'à utiliser le verbe on pourrait aussi bien dire "gâcher" à mon avis. Cependant, présenté comme anglicisme ça pourrait faire une réponse intéressante. Merci!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comme dans la définition du TLFi, *vendre la mèche* se suffit à lui-même

> - Ne vends pas la mèche !

Pour prononcer cette phrase, il faut savoir de quoi il s'agit, de quel secret il est question.

"Ne vends pas la mèche du film !" doit pouvoir se dire mais n'est pas d'usage ; ce serait un pléonasme de circonstance, car il est bien entendu que l'on parle d'un film.

Pour citer le sujet dont il est question on utilise d'autres verbes :

> - Ne révèle pas la fin du film !
> - Ne dévoile pas la fin du film !

Comment: Merci! Très bien; est-ce qu'on s'entend sur l'idée qu'on peut aussi révéler/dévoiler des trucs comme le coeur, le principe, l'essence, des détails essentiels, le point tournant ou un élément déterminant du film etc. s'il ne s'agit pas de la fin à proprement parler ?

Comment: *Vendre la mèche* marche aussi pour ces exemples. Cependant, comme cl-r l'a noté, il faut savoir de quoi il s'agit.
On peut aussi l'utiliser quand on connait un secret dans la vie courante, ce genre de choses.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Tout à fait, ces deux verbes nécessitent de définir la cible que l'on veut cacher, cible qui peut être un moment du film, un secret de famille, une intrigue... alors que *ne pas vendre la mèche* l'induit par défaut et se suffit à lui-même.

Answer (score 4):

Au Québec, une jolie traduction de "to spoil" a été proposée. Il s'agit de "divulgâcher".
cf. https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1108072/divulgacher
« Traduction de l'expression anglophone « spoiler ». C'est un mot-valise composé des mots « divulguer » et « gâcher », qui caractérise l'action de quelqu'un qui révèle un élément clé d'une série télévisée – d'un film, d'un jeu vidéo ou d'un livre – à des gens qui ne l'ont pas encore vue. »

Comment: Bonjour ! Radio-can. n'est pas une source qui fait autorité, voir plutôt [ceci](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502119) et [cela](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=divulg%c3%a2cheur&id=1915).

Answer (score 1):

Your first imperative (substituting “vendez” for “vends” to reduce false, first person indicative positives) gets close to [2,600 hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ne%20vends%20pas%20la%20meche%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22ne%20vendez%20pas%20la%20meche%22), which arguably confirms my feeling that it is perfectly fine.

For your second imperative, with “du film” added, the [seven google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ne%20vends%20pas%20la%20meche%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22ne%20vends%20pas%20la%20meche%20du%22) with “du” alone added (and back to using “vends”), however, all involve “du baratin,” which perhaps confirms my initial thought that the contexts where “vendre la mèche” is used are usually so specific and clear that “du …” is either not needed/redundant or perhaps not even grammatically correct.

In English, where “[spill the beans](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/spill+the+beans+about)” or “[let the cat out of the bag](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/let+the+cat+out+of+the+bag)” might be suitable translations for “vendre la mèche,” when the context requires further precision, the preposition that usually follows those English phrases is “about,” in the sense of “in relation to,” which is captured well by “au suject de[/du film]” or “à propos de[/du film]” in French.

Therefore, I would suggest that these two mentioned prepositional phrases or even the prepositions “sur [le film]” or “pour [le film]”  with  “vendre la mèche” would make more sense, or at least sound better to me than “de[/du film]” alone when clarification of the context is absolutely required.

Regarding other ways of saying “vendre la mèche” in French, the two Reverso links above for the English equivalents give several options, including: "cracher/lâcher le morceau"; "se mettre à table"; "tout déballer/révéler/dévoiler/dire"; and even some literal translations of “let the cat out of the bag,” although I imagine that not all of them are idiomatic when used in the film/TV context and that "DU film" (and/or parts thereof) would probably work best with "[tout] déballer/révéler/dévoiler/dire."

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I would agree with your statement on prepositions but your answer packs other useful familiar and usual expressions and tout + etc. ! Thanks!

Comment: @Amphiteóth Thanks and I readily admit that my discussion of which prepositions/phrases would work/sound better is pretty weak.  I guess I felt a need to find something other than “de/du film” primarily because I usually interpret (probably incorrectly) such “DEs” following nouns as having some sort of notion of “possession/attribution” which, if true, would, according to my understanding, permit replacing “LA mèche” with “SA mèche,” and I wasn’t sure if such a fixed idiom as this one would permit that “SA for LA” replacement without a fight!

Comment: Thanks. _The movie's wick_ vs. _the wick of the movie_. Needless to say the movie doesn't have a wick per se, and when you steer this towards a straight up possessive it does something (wrong) to the meaning i.e. makes it too concrete. I couldn't full substantiate what I'm saying; I'm really poor with formal stuff. But I hear you!

Answer (score 1):

Peut-être au Canada français mais fort probablement uniquement au *Québec*, inexistant au corpus livres de *Google*, techniquement plus restreint, et pouvant engendrer une certaine confusion ailleurs - la variante régionale:

> vendre/donner le « punch ».

À défaut de pouvoir en documenter l'origine exacte<sup>1</sup> ([exemple](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/arts-et-spectacles/television-et-radio/201112/20/01-4479771-patrice-lecuyer-nenvoie-pas-de-fleurs-mais-le-pot.php) en contexte), on peut inférer d'un fragment de terminologie: le « [*punch line*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17031675) » c'est-à-dire quelque chose comme le « mot de la fin ». Auquel s'ajoute avec le verbe, comme on le mentionne dans les autres réponses, l'idée de trahir ou de révéler... communiquer, et donc possiblement aussi, quoique sans doute rarement, avec « dire » (*il ne faut pas dire*...). Dans un engin de recherche sur le web, « donner » semble plus fréquent mais c'est trompeur. En effet il y a une certaine proximité (et donc une certaine interférence) avec « punch »(2) (*Au fig., fam. Dynamisme d'une personne, efficacité, ardeur combative, capacité de riposte.* - TLFi), de sorte qu'on retrouvera ailleurs dans la francophonie un truc qui « donne le punch dont on a besoin » dans le sens d'[*entrain*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entrain) ou de [*pep*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pep) (le sens pourra être différent dans un débit de boisson aux [*Antilles*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ti-punch)); il va sans dire que cette acception plus courante ne correspond pas à *vendre la mèche* ou à révéler ce qu'on veut faire taire à dessein.

---

<sub>1. L'expression « [*to give away the ending*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236505) » est formée avec le verbe *donner* et donc j'ai tenté de voir ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20away%20the%20punch%20line%2C*%20away%20the%20punch%2C*%20away%20the%20ending&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*%20away%20the%20punch%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgive%20away%20the%20punch%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgiving%20away%20the%20punch%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20away%20the%20punch%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btake%20away%20the%20punch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgive%20away%20the%20punch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgiving%20away%20the%20punch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btaking%20away%20the%20punch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20away%20the%20ending%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgive%20away%20the%20ending%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgiving%20away%20the%20ending%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgives%20away%20the%20ending%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgave%20away%20the%20ending%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgiven%20away%20the%20ending%3B%2Cc0)) si l'expression existe avec « punch line » en anglais mais il faut analyser les contextes(marketing, scénarisation etc.) pour voir si c'est usuel(vu la fréquence au final plutôt faible et l’échantillonnage du corpus) et ça supposerait influence qu'il faudrait documenter; ça dépasse le cadre de mon « [exploration](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=r%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20*%2Cvendre%20la%20m%C3%A8che%2Cd%C3%A9voiler%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cr%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20au%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Br%C3%A9v%C3%A9ler%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvendre%20la%20m%C3%A8che%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cd%C3%A9voiler%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20ses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9voiler%20et%3B%2Cc0) ».</sub>

Comment: Une Bleuette nous a offert le [Dictionnaire des expressions québécoises](http://www.decitre.fr/livres/dictionnaire-des-expressions-quebecoises-9782894060407.html) de Pierre DesRuisseaux, qui effectivement parle ainsi (à page 310) du mot:«PUNCH. Vendre le punch [angl. coup]; dévoiler qqch.(une plaisanterie) à contretemps, avant le moment propice.() Fr. Vendre la mèche». Dommage, je ne trouve pas cette ressource géniale sur le web (sauf pour la vendre/acheter). Pour «pep», je l’ai toujours dit au 'pluriel' (avoir/manquer du pepS), mais page 280 dudit dico vous confirme qu’il n’y a pas de «S»!