# Le substantif « spoiler » : néologisme et autres solutions ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, néologismes

Dans le domaine du *film*, on traite [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13498) de l'expression « *vendre la mèche* » en référant au substantif anglais « [*spoiler*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoiler) »; on peut noter que le verbe *vendre* y est pour beaucoup en terme de sens; sens que n'ont pas directement par ailleurs le verbe anglais « [*to spoil*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spoil) » et le verbe français « [*gâcher*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A2cher) ». De plus, on peut révéler autre chose que la *fin* ou le *punch*, et néanmoins entamer l'expérience de l’œuvre. Voici un nouvel exemple :

> — Dans le dernier film de Liam Neeson, celui-ci tient le rôle
> d'un...
>  — *Chuut*, pas de [*divulgâcheur*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502119) !! On n'a pas encore vu ce nouveau métrage : « *La nuit d'un...* » ...

---

> **divulgâcheur**
> *Domaines*
>  informatique > jeu vidéo
>  informatique > Internet
>  cinéma
>  télévision
>  art > littérature
>
> *Auteur*
>  Office québécois de la langue française, 2014
>
> ---
>
> *Définition*
>  Information divulguant une partie importante de l'intrigue d’une œuvre de fiction, qui gâche l'effet de surprise ou le
> plaisir de la découverte.
>
> *Notes*
>  L'œuvre de fiction peut être, par exemple, un film, une télésérie, un roman ou un jeu vidéo.
>  Dans le cas d'un jeu vidéo,
> la révélation d'éléments importants sur le déroulement du jeu (ex. :
> rebondissements, solutions des énigmes, dénouement de l'histoire) est
> considérée comme un divulgâcheur.
>  Sur Internet, les divulgâcheurs
> sont généralement signalés au lecteur, qui peut choisir de les lire ou
> non. Le divulgâcheur est notamment une fonction présente sur les
> forums, qui permet de cacher une partie du message afin que les autres
> ne la voient que s'ils le désirent.
>
> *Termes privilégiés*
>  *divulgâcheur*   n. m.
>  *dévoileur*   n. m.
>
> Le terme divulgâcheur a été formé à partir des mots [*divulgateur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/divulgateur) et
> [*gâcheur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A2cheur).
>
> *Terme déconseillé*
>  *spoiler*
>  L'emprunt intégral spoiler est déconseillé pour ne pas nuire à l'implantation des termes français en
> usage.
>
> [ *Grand dictionnaire terminologique* (GDT) - à « [divulgâcheur](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502119) » ]

Au [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=SPOILER), on a d'autres idées, dont « [*émécheur*](https://termexplore.wordpress.com/?s=spoiler) » de 2010.

---

Dans chaque cas en s'appuyant sur au moins une entrée parmi les sources suivantes : [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/), [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/), (Petit) *Robert*, [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/), [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra) ou dictionnaire papier, en sus de toute autre;

- Comment, d'après sa propre expérience avec la langue, envisage-t-on, au-delà de la simple opinion ou du commentaire, l'*existence*, l'*utilité*, ou la *pertinence* du néologisme « *divulgâcheur*, n.m. » dans ces domaines/en général, et pourquoi ?
- Et a-t-on d'autres solutions pour l'exemple avec « **pas de** + (substantif./groupe/locution pour « *spoiler* ») » ? Il s'agirait de quelque chose de plus compact que « *pas d'information divulguant une partie importante de l'intrigue qui gâcherait l'effet de surprise ou le plaisir de la découverte* » et de plus intéressant/usuel que « *pas de vente de mèche* ».

Comment: Note que "spoliare" est latin (je me rappelle l'avoir vu dans mes cours il y a longtemps. Maintenant, WikiPedia (pas toujours une source sûre, c'est sûr), estime que le terme pourrait avoir fait: Latin (spoliare) -> Français (espoiller) -> Anglais (spoiler) -> Français (spoiler). http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C'est la première fois que je vois ce mot *divulgâcheur*. Je comprends bien sûr avec le contexte, mais à l'oral et sans contexte il risque de ne pas être compris en France. Je ne sais pas s'il est répandu au Québec.

Je trouve étrange que *divulgâcheur* désigne l'information, et non la personne qui la révèle (ce qui aussi serait un mot utile). Un *gâcheur* est une personne qui gâche, il y a donc là une incohérence. Pour l'information, je préfèrerais *divulgâchage*.

Je n'ai jamais vu « *émécheur* » et je ne comprendrais pas sauf si ça se devine de manière très évidente dans le contexte.

Dans l'exemple que tu donnes, pour dire « *don't reveal any spoilers* », on utiliserait d'autres manières de tourner la phrase. Du plus au moins idiomatique à mon oreille :

> — Chut, ne gâche pas le suspense.
>   — Chut, ne révèle pas la fin.
>   — Chut, ne révèle/gâche pas la surprise.
>   — Chut, ne vends pas la mêche.

Je ne sais pas si *suspense* est accepté au Québec, mais en France, c'est un mot parfaitement courant ; il a un parfum d'empreint anglais mais qui s'estompe. La prononciation est encore majoritairement [syspεns] (prononciation à l'anglaise) mais [syspɑ ̃:s] (lecture phonétique en français) s'entend aussi.

Je ne vois pas de bonne manière de traduire *spoiler* en lui-même, par exemple dans des expressions comme « *spoiler-free* ». L'utilisation du mot anglais (« sans spoiler », prononcé [sɑ̃ spɔjlœʁ] ou [sɑ̃ spɔjlɛʁ]) sera peut-être comprise, mais elle sera vécue comme un anglicisme et pas forcément comprise par des gens qui ne pratiquent pas l'anglais au moins sur Internet.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Je n'ai pas proposé de forme averbale parce qu'il n'y a pas vraiment de mot qui traduit le nom *spoiler*, alors qu'il y a des manières de traduire l'action *spoil*.

Comment: "L'utilisation du mot anglais (« sans spoiler », prononcé [sɑ̃ spɔjlœʁ] ou [sɑ̃ spɔjlɛʁ]) sera peut-être comprise, mais elle sera vécue comme un anglicisme et pas forcément comprise par des gens qui ne pratiquent pas l'anglais au moins sur Internet." > Cela dit, divulgacheur a très peu de chance d'être compris par qui que soit, tout comme beaucoup de néologismes techniques (ou pas, d'ailleurs) francais

Answer (score 3):

Si l'on accepte d'utiliser une périphrase plutôt qu'un mot :

> Quel *gâcheur de suspense* ce type !

Sinon on peut essayer les transpositions :

> - Untel, critique cinématographique, a été le *naufrageur* du film en divulguant le dénouement avant la première projection publique.
> - La *révélation* ou la *divulgation* de cette intrigue seront considérées comme des tentatives de corruption, de dégradation et même d'attentat à l’œuvre, un outrage  à son auteur (... si l'on utilise l'outrance  de certains plumitifs).

Pour un cuisinier  un *gâte-sauce* est celui qui, par incompétence, ignorance, maladresse, stupidité, vient gâter par un geste inapproprié la sauce réussie du *maître queux* :

> - "Ne viens pas jouer les *gâte-sauce* en révélant l'intrigue du livre !"

Pour une œuvre on peut dire aussi *dévastateur, vandale*, dans le sens où il y a destruction de l'intrigue, du suspense, du mystère onirique :

> - "Cela a eu un effet *dévastateur* sur le public qui n'a pas toléré de connaître la fin de l'histoire".

---

Il y a sûrement d'autres transpositions possibles, il faudrait des phrases complètes à traduire ; certains choix de mots dépendent du contexte.

*Divulgâcheur* est un mot inusité dans l’hexagone (peu enclin à créer des mots valises dans le domaine culturel) qui ne connaît que le *divulgateur* pour les informations autorisées :

*Spoiler* seul :

> - *Traître !* ou *Ah le traître* [il a révélé la fin] !
> - *Bandit !*

*No spoilers* seul :

> - Pas de divulgateurs.

... seul endroit où la négation sous entend que divulguer serait gâcher le travail ; mais cela sera plutôt compris comme une invite à ne pas parler du film ou du roman en entier, et non de sa fin.

> - Ne pas révéler la fin.
> - Silence ! Gardez le dénouement pour vous !
> - Ne révélez rien du suspense ! *ou* Ne rien révéler du suspense.

Sous réserve du contexte, avec *pas de* :

> Pas de *divulgateur, propagateur, vulgarisateur* de l'intrigue, de la fin, du mystère, du suspense ...

*Divulgateur, propagateur, vulgarisateur* sont des mots qui cernent chacun dans leur contexte une action précise dans le domaine de l'information, mais ils ne sont pas sur-employés dans les conversations courantes. S'ils ont besoins de précision on leur adjoint adjectifs et compléments à volonté. Pour créer un mot nouveau il faudrait que la périphrase soit unique (ce n'est pas le cas ici) et fatigante à répéter, on chercherait alors une racine gréco-latine plutôt qu'un mot-valise.

Comment: @Amphiteóth J'ai complété ma réponse

Comment: @Amphiteóth l'anglais sera toujours (ou quasiment) plus compact que le français, c'est un fait, on ne va pas changer la langue pour qu'elle ressemble à une autre ;)

Comment: @YohannV. C'est davantage dans le sens de la forme sans verbe "pas de qqc." puisque c'est de cette forme dont je parlais en question. Mais en effet. Merci!

Comment: @Amphiteóth dernier ajout : avec pas de.

Answer (score 3):

Personne n'a parlé du verbe **spolier** (je n'en trouve plus trace), et je ne sais plus si je l'avais proposé à l'époque.

De par la proximité étymologique, et au final, l'orthographe actuelle, si proche, il m'apparaît comme une évidence.

Dans [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/spolier) :

> - A. − Spolier qqn (de qqc.).Synon. déposséder.
> - B. − Spolier qqc.Synon. soustraire, voler.Sans respect pour le droit sacré des propriétés[...]

Ne pourrait-on pas imaginer un

> -Chuut, ne me spolie pas de l'intrigue !!

ou un

> -Chuut, ne me spolie pas du suspense !!

Et, de par le contexte, directement :

> -Chuut, ne me spolie pas !

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Je note à chaque fois la présence de la notion de vol/dépouillement, pas de destruction/saccage mais de *violence*.

Comment: Voici les liens que j'ai consultés comme complément (pour l'éty. anglaise et l'ancien français _espillier_) : [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=spoil&allowed_in_frame=0), [DmF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=complXpcYXcgac;ISIS=isis_dmf2015.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s0c221d04;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;XXX=4;;). Merci !

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Effectivement sur etymonline, il semble qu'à partir de 1560 apparaisse un sens de "destroy, ruin, damage so as to render useless" mais est-ce qu'il remplace le sens précédent ou s'ajoute en dépendant du contexte? Je ne lis pas assez de dicos pour le dire, qu'en pensez-vous?

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il le remplace mais je n'ai aucune expertise et je suis francophone, en plus je n'ai pas accès au merveilleux _OED_. Mais vous pouvez parfois trouver d'autres indices avec disons un truc qui ressemble à une vieille version du _Oxford_, soit le _Century_ : [lien](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=07&page=534&query=spoiler). (mais noter que ce n'est pas à jour, c'est un peu comme le _Littré_...).

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt J'adore la loupe en mouseover ! :)