# « Pas de spoiling » : est-ce usuel uniquement à l'extérieur du Québec ?

Tags: anglais, usage, anglicismes, emprunts, fréquence-utilisation

On a déjà [traité](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14082) du nom et du verbe « spoiler » pour *divulgâcheur/divulgâcher*. [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/spoiler_1) affirme que l'emploi de l'anglicisme est critiqué au Québec mais « généralement pas en France », à tout le moins pour le nom, qu'il se rapporte au fait de dire la suite ou à l'élément du véhicule. Mais en lisant le [billet](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/spoiler) de l'Académie française de 2014 concernant le verbe je note le propos suivant :

> Cet anglicisme peut être aisément évité tout comme le substantif qui
> en découle, *spoiling* (*Pas de spoiling !*).

Je suis familier avec l'emprunt pour le verbe (*ne spoile pas !*) ou pour le nom (*pas de spoiler !*) mais je ne reconnais pas le substantif/participe présent en *-ing* « *spoiling* ».

- Ce emploi est-il uniquement en usage à l'extérieur du Québec ?
- Dit-on plus souvent « pas de *spoiler* » ou « pas de *spoiling* », quelle
  est la fréquence relative ?

Comment: On entend aussi (plus ?) souvent « pas de spoil ! »

Comment: Oui, j'ai déjà entendu « **pas de spoil** »  mais je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu  « **pas de spoiling** » et encore moins  « **pas de spoilage** ».

Comment: Je n'accepterais pas davantage « spoil » vu le conflit avec « spoils of war » mais ça c'est peut-être dû à une norme différente de l'emprunt ou peut-être que des gens plus jeunes que moi utilisent ça et que je suis _off_. En France j'ai l'impression que quand on emprunte, on intègre davantage ou on joue plus librement avec l'emprunt alors qu'ici ça ressemble plus à un _code switch_ et la prononciation reste proche de celle de l'anglais etc. N'hésitez pas à répondre !

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle absolument, et ce jeu avec l'emprunt est possible parce que l'emploi de l'anglais donne une précision sémantique sans équivoque et permet une grande liberté tant qu'on reconnait a peu près le mot d'origine. Quant à accepter ou ne pas accepter "spoil", c'est une question différente de celle de la fréquence ;)

Comment: Si par ''élément du véhicule' vous faites référence au becquet d'une voiture, je ne pense pas que l'utilisation de spoiler soit passée en language courant, en France en tout cas. A part peut etre parmi les férus d'automobiles.